# Return n value of array Function and list in while loop PHP

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to show list of countries by the use of PHP function.

Here's the database value that I'm retrieving on. **(cropped)**

[image]

Here's the function that I'm retrieving the data.

**Code:**

```
public function get_countries() {

    $list_country = array();
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT name FROM country");
    $query->execute();

    while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $list_country[] = $r['name'];
    }

    return $list_country;
}
```

Then here's the code where I echo all the data.

```
<?php
    while (list($country) = $general->get_countries()) {
        echo $country;
    }
?>
```

Unfortunately, it just all echo the same value over and over again.

[image]

Any solution for this? Like echo-ing all the data instead of the same data over and over again?

Comment: Try replacing while with foreach($list_country as $final).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
    $country_array = $general->get_countries();
    foreach ($country_array as $country) {
        echo $country;
    }
?>
```

You don't need the `while()` as you already fetched all countries with `get_countries()` function. Moreover, with `list()` you retrieve only the `n` array elements where `n` is the number of variables inside `list()` function.

### So, why are you getting every time the same value?

Because you're calling every time a db function for read country content and every time you're retrieving the same value (the first)

Answer (score 1):

$query = $PDO->prepare("SELECT blah FROM table");

$country = array();
`while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $country[] = $row['blah'];
 }`

That code worked for me. You can set some exception if the query returns null this would suppress your warnings in the while loop.

Hope that helps